# where to put the formatting logic in MVC rest api

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller

I would like to know where will be considered "best practice" to put the data formatting logic in a node/express rest api application. I know normally, it should be put in the view but as in a node rest api there is practically no view, you just send json in the controller doing

```
res.json({somedata})
```

I have some database queries that gives me the raw data, but after the queries with relations I need to format it and give the response, should I format it in the controller after getting the data from model or should I format it in Model and just send the response in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a service to execute any modification your data needs and call that inside the controller function, an example structure might be like

```
├───models
│   ├───user.model.js
├───routes
│   ├───user.route.js
├───services
│   ├───user.service.js
├───controllers
│   ├───user.controller.js
```

You can read more about it here: https://sodocumentation.net/node-js/topic/10785/route-controller-service-structure-for-expressjs

Comment: real apps of any size wouldn't use that structure, its taken from express defaults which is bad, over placing all thats needed in `./module/user/` and using package.json in each module to load them, vs spreading out all the code in many directories for additional coupling